# T values of ARIMA parameter estimates

Tags: regression, t-test, arima, t-distribution

The SAS proc ARIMA documentation states that "The t values reported in the table of parameter estimates are approximations whose accuracy depends on the validity of the model, the nature of the model, and the length of the observed series. When the length of the observed series is short and the number of estimated parameters is large with respect to the series length, the t approximation is usually poor. Probability values that correspond to a t distribution should be interpreted carefully because they may be misleading."

I have been searching through textbooks and the internet for elaboration on this. I am aware of the fact that regressions on nonstationary time series can lead to "spurious regression" because the t-ratios do not follow a t distribution, but I am looking for a more technical explanation of why they do not follow a t distribution. I have read the classic Granger and Newbold paper from 1974 and understand that they, and later others, used simulations to empirically demonstrate the spurious regression phenomenon, but am I looking for an explanation that can be derived from statistical theory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers